# second view controller still react to first ViewController swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm developing an app where I had to build my own gesture recognition (Apple's were too precise)

I need to use a second view controller (settings), and when I'm on the second one, it still react to the first one.

Where it's very problematic it's that with these gesture I control things in the house (such as lighting, music or even more), so imagine you click on a button on the second view and it light up the room, or you swipe down on the second view and the music is cut...

I'm using a segue to go to the SecondViewController

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender:self)
```

I've created another swift file for the second view controller, where, for now, there is nothing.

Do you have any idea what's going on and how I can solve that?

Thanks!

EDIT: As requested, here is more code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
//Variables definition

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ascending = false
    UIScreen.main.wantsSoftwareDimming = true
    UIScreen.main.brightness = (0.0)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.timer.invalidate()
    isPinched = false
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    startTime = getCurrentMillis()

    for touch in touches{
        let point = touch.location(in: self.view)
        for (index,finger)  in fingers.enumerated() {
            if finger == nil {
                fingers[index] = String(format: "%p", touch)

                if (finger1.isEmpty){
                    finger1 = [point.x, point.y]
                } 
                //And so on until finger10
                break
            }
        }
    }

    //If the gesture is long enough, I have a special recognition (longPress)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(increaseValue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    if ascending {
        ascending = false
    }
    else {
        ascending = true
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

    for touch in touches {
        let point = touch.location(in: self.view)
        for (index,finger) in fingers.enumerated() {
            if let finger = finger, finger == String(format: "%p", touch) {
                switch (index){
                case 0 :
                    finger1 += [point.x, point.y]
                //And so on until case 9 / finger10
                default :
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    endTime = getCurrentMillis()

    for touch in touches {
        for (index,finger) in fingers.enumerated() {
            if let finger = finger, finger == String(format: "%p", touch) {
                fingers[index] = nil
                break
            }
        }
    }

    direction[0] = ""
    direction[1] = ""
    direction[2] = ""
    direction[3] = ""
    direction[4] = ""

    if finger1.count != 0 {
        direction[0] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger1, index: 0)
    }
    if finger2.count != 0 {
        direction[1] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger2, index: 1)
    }
    if finger3.count != 0 {
        direction[2] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger3, index: 2)
    }
    if finger4.count != 0 {
        direction[3] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger4, index: 3)
    }
    if finger5.count != 0 {
        direction[4] = GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger5, index: 4)
    }


    if Int64(endTime - startTime) < 600 {
//My gesture recognition 
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
        self.directionLabel.text = self.labelUpdate
        self.finger1 = []
        self.finger2 = []
        self.finger3 = []
        self.finger4 = []
        self.finger5 = []
        self.finger6 = []
        self.finger7 = []
        self.finger8 = []
        self.finger9 = []
        self.finger10 = []
    }
}

//One of the function I call
func swipeLeftTwo(){
    request(urlAdress: "Url Adress")
}

func swipeRightFour(){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender:self)
}
}
```

In the second view controller:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelTe: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labelTe.text = "something changed"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more code, from this information it is really hard to determine what might be wrong. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is my first time hearing a problem with `Apple's(gestures) were too precise`, but you might want to look into [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html), it might solve your issue.

Comment: @BenOng in fact the Ipad will not be used in a conventional way, it will be fixed to the wall, and people will interact with it when passing by (When you leave a room you don't stop in front of your switch to turn off the light, do you?) We'd like to "replace" a swift by the Ipad if you want, that way gesture can't be very precise.

Comment: It sounds like you have attached your gesture recogniser to the root window or something; but without code we are just guessing

Comment: @DávidPásztor ok, I'll try but on this problem I don't have much to say. The main thing is that I override touchesBegan / touchesMoved and touchesEnded. Maybe that's were I've problem.

Comment: @Hawkydoky well, without seeing code, we can't really help. If you know you did override some methods that might be connected to your issue, don't you think you should include the code of those functions in your question?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Just added the code. Not everything as it's very long in fact.

Comment: Maybe you could in a boolean check so that the code only runs if it is true, then make the boolean false as it moves to the second controller, and true in the first one. Only guessing though, it is difficult without seeing more of your project.

Comment: Is your second ViewController is using the second class in the storyboard? You might've forgotten to set it.

Comment: @EthanHumphries I think you may have point out something. The custom class of the **SecondViewController** is set to SecondViewController, BUT the UIView custom class is not set to anything and I've no idea what it can be linked to... Maybe that's because my class where I do the gesture recognition is my main class and putting it as a child one could solve the problem... What do you think?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the UIView shouldn't have a specific class set, assuming you are talking about the default one that comes with the ViewController, and not an additional one that you've added in. My views on the project I have open right now don't let me set my cocoa touch class as it's custom class.

Comment: @EthanHumphries ok, so I gave a try to what I was saying, ie putting my gesture recognition in the second view controller and setting in first. It work great... Until I get to the second view, once there it never leaves and always recognize gesture even on the first view... I guess there is something with overriding touchesBegan and the other as I already had that kind of problem when I was trying to use XMCircleGestureRecognozer class. Is it possible "to kill" the view when leaving ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150001/discussion-between-hawkydoky-and-ethan-humphries).